# What is dimension order of numpy shape for image data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, shapes

I am using `nibabel` lib to load data from nii file. I read the document of the lib at http://nipy.org/nibabel/gettingstarted.html, and found that

> This information is available without the need to load anything of the main image data into the memory. Of course there is also access to the image data as a NumPy array

This is my code to load the data and it shapes

```
import nibabel as nib
img = nib.load('example.nii')
data = img.get_data()
data = np.squeeze(data)
data = np.copy(data, order="C")
print data.shape
```

I got the result

```
128, 128, 64
```

What is order of data shape? Is it `WidthxHeightxDepth`? And my input must  arranged as `depth, height, width`. So I will use `input=data.transpose(2,0,1)`. Is it right? Thanks all

Update: I found that the Numpy will read the image by order `Height x Width x Depth` as the reference http://www.python-course.eu/images/axis.jpeg

Comment: What's the Numpy documentation say?

Comment: I found that, axis=0 is height, axis=1 is width and axis=2 is depth. Is it right? Like this http://www.python-course.eu/images/axis.jpeg

Comment: I meant to go find the shape function on the Numpy site

Comment: The simplest way to answer your own question is to run the code on a sample image of known dimensions.

Comment: Your transpose is wrong. If the input is `(W, H, D)` you get `(D, W, H)`. You can call `transpose` without arguments to simply reverse the order of dimensions, which gives you the desired `(D, H, W)`. An easy way to determine the interpretation of the shape is to load data with differently sized dimensions (e.g. `(128, 64, 32)`) and compare to the shape you get.

Comment: @cricket_007: That won't actually help since `shape()` doesn't describe the mapping of the characteristics of the image to the data structure.

Comment: @kazemakase: Because the shape function is called after line `data = np.copy(data, order="C")` and due to the dimension order of numpy like `(W, H, D)`. So I think print result `128, 128, 64` will be W=128, H=128, and D=48. My transpose code just want to convert to DxWxH.

Comment: @user8264 if `(D, W, H)` is what you want your transpose is correct but you wrote you need `depth, height, width` in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Thanks for your point out. How about the main question. What is order of array?

Comment: http://nipy.org/nibabel/coordinate_systems.html#the-scanner-axes

Comment: @kmario23: Please check it again. Is it `WxHxD` or `HxWxD`. I think it is `HxWxD` in Numpy

Comment: @user8264 You're right, it's always `(H, W, D)` because of the terminology that NumPy uses to `(axis=0, axis=1, axis=2)` or analogously `(Y, X, Z)` axes if you'd like to visualize it that way.

Comment: @user8264 updated my answer.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

OK, here's my take:

Using `scipy.ndimage.imread('img.jpg', mode='RGB')`, the resulting array will always have this order: `(H, W, D)` i.e. (height, width, depth) because of the terminology that numpy uses for ndarrays `(axis=0, axis=1, axis=2)` or analogously `(Y, X, Z)` if one would like to visualize in 3 dimensions.

```
# read image
In [21]: img = scipy.ndimage.imread('suza.jpg', mode='RGB')

# image shape as (H, W, D)
In [22]: img.shape
Out[22]: (634, 1366, 3)

# transpose to shape as (D, H, W)
In [23]: tr_img = img.transpose((-1, 0, 1))    

In [23]: tr_img.shape
Out[23]: (3, 634, 1366)
```

---

If you consider the img_shape as a tuple,

```
#  index    (0,   1,    2)
img_shape = (634, 1366, 3)
# or index  (-3,  -2,  -1)
```

Choose which one is a convenient way for you to remember.

---

**NOTE**: The [**scipy.ndimage.imread()** API has been removed since Scipy 1.2.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html). So, it is now recommended to use [imageio.imread()](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html#imageio.imread), which reads the image and returns Array, a subclass of numpy array, following the same conventions discussed above.

```
# read image
$ img = imageio.imread('suza.jpg', format='jpg')

# convert the image to a numpy array
$ img_np = np.asarray(img)
```

---

**PS**: It should also be noted that libraries like tensorflow also (almost) follows the same convention as numpy.

[tf.image_decode_jpeg()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_image)  returns:

> A Tensor of type uint8. 3-D with shape `[height, width, channels]`

Comment: Thanks kmario23 for your answer. I would like to know why is it `transpose((-1, 0, 1)) `, instead of `transpose((2, 0, 1))`

Comment: @user8264 Yours is right as well. It's just another way of writing the indices (of a tuple/list).

Comment: Thanks. So, I used `data = np.copy(data, order="C")` in my code (in question). Do I need to remove the line?

Comment: @user8264 Yes, I think there is no need for the `squeeze` and `copy` operations. The data you load using `img.get_data()` is itself a numpy array